# how to use groupby in mvc?

Tags: c#, linq

This is my query .

```
 var query = from sbw in _sbwRepository.Table
                            orderby sbw.CountryId, sbw.StateProvinceId, sbw.Zip, sbw.ShippingMethodId, sbw.From                           
                            select sbw;
```

How to groupby "sbw.CountryId" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear what results you're trying to get. For example, you *could* just use:

```
var query = from sbw in _sbwRepository.Table
            orderby sbw.CountryId, sbw.StateProvinceId, sbw.Zip,
                    sbw.ShippingMethodId, sbw.From                           
            group sbw by sbw.CountryId;
```

... or you could use `group ... by ... into` if you want to do more work afterwards.

See the [MSDN page on grouping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386922.aspx) for more examples.